# unable to import scss file as react module

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, module

I have a Dashboard.tsx file and Dashboard.scss file (I'm using vscode)

I'm trying to import the scss file like so: `Import * as style from './Dashboard.scss'`
but it can't find the module,

I tried also `import style from './Dashboard.scss'`
same error,
even tried renaming to `Dashboard.module.scss` which eliminated the problem but react code won't compile.

Comment: You should `import "./Dashboard.scss"` or `import styles from "./Dashboard.module.scss"`

Answer (score -1):

Don't import it as named. simply use `import "./Dashboard.scss";` and It should work.

Comment: but I want to import is as named, I did it before,so I will wait for another answer.